# How to make where its required to choose multiple words

Tags: tags, title

I have this string that makes it so you have to choose one of the options within it before posting on reddit which is `^\[(asdasa|osdff)\]` you can add more options by sperating them with another pipe

The string makes it so you have to choose one of the options within and put in brackets at the being of a post title

EX: `^\[(asdasa|osdff)\]` = either [asdasa] or [osdff]
Reddit title : [asdasa] today blah blah..

And I want to make so you have to choose two or more but of differnt strings so I tried just repeating it but with differnt options on the second list

so I tried something like this

Ex: `^\[(osdff|yysjdj)\]`
`^\[(sdgasdg|hofkhm)\]`
Reddit title: [hofkhm][osdff] yesterday blah..

But doing this doesnt make it where you have to choose one from each instead you can choose any of the options from either list

Comment: Are you asking about regular expressions (regex)?

Comment: @PresidentJamesK.Polk  just started to learn code, so I don't know what a regular expression is.  I might not be explaining what I want clearly, but what I want is a list that force you to put two or more words in brackets at the beginning of a Reddit post title.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.